# XSLT sort child nodes under different parent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to sort xml with xslt but the problem is that my code only sort elements under specific node, here is a sample xml:

```
<region name="Germany">
    <company name="Mercedes" rank="2" />
    <company name="BMW" rank="3" />
</region>
<region name="Japan">
    <company name="Toyota" rank="1" />
    <company name="Mazda" rank="4" />
</region>
```

I tried the folowing but it didn't work

```
<xsl:template match="region">
    <Companies>
        <xsl:for-each select="company">
            <xsl:sort select="@rank" />
            <xsl:call-template name="companies">
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Companies>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="companies">
     <Company>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
     </Company>
</xsl:template>
```

the output should be:

```
<Companies>
    <Company>Toyota</Company>
    <Company>Mercedes</Company>
    <Company>BMW</Company>
    <Company>Mazda</Company>
</Companies>
```

Comment: You will need to be more specific as to how the complete result has to look? Do you want one `parentNode` result element to contain all sorted `node` elements?

Comment: I just want to output in the correct number orders 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the exact type and result you want. Is that just the sequence of numbers you have shown or any XML/HTML wrapper elements? You can of course sort `//parentNode/node` or use a different `match` than you have currently, but it is hard to make suggestions if you show only fragments with no context.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I edited my example to show the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown any container element for those `region` elements but assuming you have them inside one common container write a template matching that container (e.g. named `root` in the sample code below) and then I would simply suggest to apply-templates to the `company` grandchildren with an `xsl:sort` included based on the `rank` attribute.

Then add a template transforming from the attribute based `company` input elements to a value based element and you are done:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <Companies>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="region/company">
              <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(@rank)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </Companies>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="company">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6B

Matching on each `region` doesn't seem to make sense if you want to process them all together in a sorted way.

Answer (score 1):

From the output it seems you want to sort by rank and not name.

Regarding the sorting happening withing the node, since your template is running for each region and so the sorting is for company nodes within a region.
You could run template for parent of region and then iterate over  elements and sort by name.
Here is the template with the matching output.

```xslt
<xsl:template match="*[region]">
    <Companies>
        <xsl:for-each select="region/company">
            <xsl:sort select="@rank" />
            <xsl:call-template name="companies" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Companies>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="companies">
     <Company>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
     </Company>
</xsl:template>
```